# I want to create thumbnail from video url of server in android

Tags: android, mediametadataretriever

My code,

```
public static Bitmap retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath) throws Throwable {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = null;
    try {
        mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath, new HashMap<String, String>());
        else
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
        //   mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath);
        bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Throwable(
                "Exception in retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)"
                        + e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null) {
            mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

This is Create thumbnail but take much time I used this with `ListView` then `ListView` being hangup.

Comment: This is not "your code". It is pretty obvious you took if from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32689023/1250021 and you should credit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need run this task in Async Method Like this in `onBindViewHolder()` if you are using `RecycleView` or put on `getView()` if your are using `ListView`:

```
 new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
            Bitmap bitmapVideo;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                try {
                   //Your method call here
                    bitmapVideo =retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(strings[0]);
                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String id) {
                super.onPostExecute(id);
                if (bitmapVideo != null) {
                  //Load your bitmap here
                    holder.imgVideoThumb.setImageBitmap(bitmapVideo);
                }
            }
        }.execute(getYourVideolink());
```

For better efficiency you save the bitmap image in local and before calling `AsyncTask()` check weather this image is already save in local if its their than load from local and no new to run `AsyncTask()` again

Comment: Thank you bro.
But then also have one issue when i scroll listview then all other thumbnail set on video

Comment: I didn't get you ??

Comment: Than you have to manage using `Viewholder` and saving image in local and loading from local

Comment: My Listview having more then one video when i scroll my listview then thumbnail set but on mismatch video 
This occur because we set image view in asyncTask

Comment: Your better use `RecycleView` for more efficency because 'ListView' is not depracted..it will work fine in recycleview