# Quickblox video thumbnail issue android

Tags: android, quickblox

Is their any way to get thumbnail of video which is uploaded in Quickblox server. Currently receiving video url but don't know how to get thumbnail .

Comment: You can refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571465/i-want-to-create-thumbnail-from-video-url-of-server-in-android/42571631#42571631

Comment: Thanks for comment it works bro @BurhanuddinRashid