# How to get thumbnail of url video which is not available in phone storage?

Tags: android

Here i tried below code but not get result

```
Bitmap bitmap =ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(video,MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: tried `MediaMetadataRetriever`?

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571465/i-want-to-create-thumbnail-from-video-url-of-server-in-android/42571631#42571631

Comment: Try to use `MediaMetadataRetriever`