# generate thumbnail of videos from server and display in GridView

Tags: android, thumbnails

I am fetching data from the server which includes images and videos and displaying then in same Grid after generating the thumbnails of the videos.
I am using this code to generate thumbnail of the video-

bitmap = ThumbnailFromVideo.retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(baseUrl+videoPath[i]);

The code is generating Thumbnail but taking a lot of time which is not feasible for any of the application.
Is there any other way to get the thumbnails faster.

Comment: I'm sure that there is no faster way to do that on the client side. I'm sure that it is not a client-side task to generate a thumbnail. You should implement it on the server-side.

Comment: Please check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954894/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-thumbnail-from-a-video-url-in-android

Comment: Thank you @Vlad Matvienko,@vinod