# How Can I create video thumbnail or snapshot or frame capture on videoview from url?

Tags: android, android-videoview

What is the simple way to create video thumbnail or snapshot or frame capture from url?
I am using videoview and it has black screen before start.
My code is:

```
String vidAddress = URL_trailers_mp4;
Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
VideoView vidView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
vidView.seekTo(0);
```

And it does not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437120/get-thumbnail-image-of-video-from-video-url

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533857/how-can-i-create-a-thumbnail-of-a-video-url-in-android

Comment: They are not helpfull

Comment: You find a solution? I am stuck on this issue...

Comment: Did not find, but I found youtube link and used youtube api.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just simple

```
videoview.seekto(0);
```

will help. It should set first key frame of the video as videoview preview

Answer (score 0):

I found some rough decision: seekto, start and pause got me image on video.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
FileOutputStream out;
File land=new File(URL);// image file use to create image u can give any path.
Bitmap bitmap=ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);//filePath is your video file path.
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

out=new  FileOutputStream(land.getPath());
out.write(byteArray);
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `vidView.seekTo(0);` to 
`vidView.seekTo(100);
//100 milliseconds (0.1 s) clip of video`

And you may create a thumbnail with the following code:

```
                ImageView imageThumbnail = new ImageView(Video.this);
                Bitmap bmThumbnail;
                bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoSource, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html).
example：

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(context, vidUri);
Bitmap bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(expectPosition);
```

However,there is no guarentee that the data source has a frame located at the position. When this happens, a frame nearby will be returned.